# PHP: Allow users to make posts with certain tags

Tags: php, html, escaping, sanitization

Users on my site can post news items. But right now, it's all honor system as far as HTML goes.

```
function postNewsItem($subject, $body, $userid){
  $time = time();
  $subject = mysql_real_escape_string($subject);
  $body = mysql_real_escape_string($body);
  $q = "INSERT INTO news (subject, body, userid) VALUES ('$subject', '$body', '$userid')";
  $result = mysql_query($q, $this->connection);
  return 1;
}
```

I want users to be able to link to images, build tables, bold their words, etc etc, but I don't want them to be able to link to malicious scripts and what-not. I know there are ways to escape HTML from user input, but is there a way to do that while allowing certain tags?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [HTML PUrifier](http://htmlpurifier.org/). It allows you to basically create a whitelist of allows tags and it filters out anything else out.

Answer (score 6):

you may use strip_tags and allow certain tags

[www.php.net/strip_tags](http://www.php.net/strip_tags)

```
<?php
$allow = '<table><thead><th><tr><td><tbody><tfoot><img><a><b><i><u>';

$body = mysql_real_escape_string(strip_tags($body, $allow));
?>
```

of course you will need sanitize some attributes